# Como converter dados latin1_swedish_ci para utf8_bin em php?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, pdo

Peguei um script SQL que "monta" 3 tabelas, uma com país, uma com estados e outra com cidades brasileiras.
O script torna a `collection`, dos nomes, em `latin1_swedish_ci` e eu precisava que fosse `utf8_bin`, pois os nomes com acento gera um outro caracter, e ainda tenho que colocar esses nomes em formato `json`.

Meu HTML:

```
<div align="center">
<form>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="estado.idEstado">
    Estado <input type="text" ng-model="estado.nome">
    Sala <input type="text" ng-model="estado.sala">
    <button ng-click="atualizarEstado(estado)">Atualizar</button><br>
</form>
```

Meu php:

```
<?php
include_once("conPDO.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$id = $_GET['idEstado'];

$buscarEstado=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM estado WHERE idEstado=:id ");
$buscarEstado->bindValue(":id", $id);
$buscarEstado->execute();

//header('Content-Type: application/json');

$return = array();

while ($linha=$buscarEstado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $return = $linha;
        print_r($return);
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

No console aparece isso:

```
Array
    (
        [idEstado] => 4
        [nome] => Amap�
        [uf] => AP
        [pais] => 1
        [sala] => 
    )
```

Comment: Teste fazer o seguinte `$return = utf8_encode($linha);` e `json_encode($return JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`. Veja se resolve.

Comment: Apareceu essa mensagem no console:
"<b>Warning</b>:  utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/VigilantesComunitarios/admin/php/pegaEstado.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />"

Comment: Tenta então somente `echo json_encode($return JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` deixa o return como estava.

Comment: Nada... Apresenta esse erro no console:
"GET http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/VigilantesComunitarios/admin/php/pegaEstado.php?idEstado=4 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Certo, testa isso `echo json_encode($return, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` com isso ele vai tentar fazer todos os decodes que tem.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @MoisesGama, mas já consegui.
Eu fiz isso:
$linha['nome'] = mb_convert_encoding($linha['nome'], "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: Deu outro problema... O nome, agora, é exibido, na listagem, dessa forma AmapÃ¡ ao invés de Amapá. E se tento editar pra corrigir, não aparece mais no campo de edição.

Comment: @MoisesGama, fiz isso:
$linha['nome'] = json_encode($linha, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  array_push($linha, $linha['nome']);
  $return = $linha;

E apareceu isso no console:
"Array
(
    [idEstado] => 4
    [nome] => 
    [uf] => AP
    [pais] => 1
    [sala] => Eama4
    [0] => 
)
{"idEstado":"4","nome":false,"uf":"AP","pais":"1","sala":"Eama4","0":false}"

Comment: coloca isso antes da include `header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");` e veja como imprime no `print_r($return);` sem colocar no `JSON`

Comment: Antes de fazer o que você me sugeriu, fiz de uma forma que está dando certo, PORÉM, quando eu atualizo o dado, o nome vem "estragado" hehehe

Será que se eu fizer o que o que você está me sugerindo, no php que atualiza os dados, dará certo?

Answer (score 1):

Execute uma query setando o charset do banco de dados

```
$pdo->query('SET NAMES UTF-8');
```

ou se o seu banco estiver usando ISO-8859-1

```
$pdo->query('SET NAMES LATIN1');
```